# How to format a Grid command

Tags: formatting, grid-layouts

Creating some extra notes for students in a trig class.   A bare bones table can be created in Mathematica using the line below.

```
Grid[{
  {"",  "Quadrant", SpanFromLeft}, {"Ratio", "I", "II", "III", 
   "IV"}, {"sin \[Theta]", "+", "+", "-", "-"},
  {"cos \[Theta]", "+", "+", "-", "-"},
  {"tan \[Theta]", "+", "+", "-", "-"}}, Frame -> All, 
 ItemSize -> {3, 2}]
```

The textbook has the following table.

[image]

I absolutely don't need the table I am creating to look exactly like that, but trying to use Mathematica,  wondering what kinds of things I can do to "improve" the look of the bare bones table creating using the  Grid command.

Any comments or help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks a lot nicer with this change...  a start... `Grid[{
  {"",  "Quadrant", SpanFromLeft}, {"Ratio", "I", "II", "III", 
   "IV"}, {Style["sin \[Theta]", "DisplayFormula"], "+", "+", "-", 
   "-"},
  {Style["cos \[Theta]", "DisplayFormula"], "+", "+", "-", "-"},
  {Style["tan \[Theta]", "DisplayFormula"], "+", "+", "-", "-"}}, 
 Frame -> All, ItemSize -> {3, 2}]`

Comment: I'll let someone else improve this: `Text[Grid[{{"", Style["Quadrant", Bold], SpanFromLeft}, Style[#, Bold] & /@ {"Ratio", "I", "II", "III", "IV"}, {ToString[Sin[θ], TraditionalForm], "+", "+", "-", "-"}, {ToString[Cos[θ], TraditionalForm], "+", "+", "-", "-"}, {ToString[Tan[θ], TraditionalForm], "+", "+", "-", "-"}}, Background -> {None, {RGBColor["#C0D8F1"], RGBColor["#C0D8F1"]}}, Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.5, 0.7], ItemSize -> {3, 2}]]`

Answer (score 8):

The items in the original table look a lot like buttons. Lets try that approach:

```
{{"", "Quadrant", SpanFromLeft},
 {"Ratio", "I", "II", "III", "IV"},
 {Sin[\[Theta]], "+", "+", "-", "-"},
 {Cos[\[Theta]], "+", "+", "-", "-"},
 {Tan[\[Theta]], "+", "+", "-", "-"}} //
    MapAt[OperatorApplied[Button][Background -> RGBColor["#C0D8F1"]], {1,1 ;; 2}] //
    MapAt[OperatorApplied[Button][Background -> RGBColor["#C0D8F1"]], {2, All}] //
    MapAt[OperatorApplied[Button][Background -> White], {3;;-1, All}] //
    OperatorApplied[Grid][
       {ItemStyle -> {Automatic, {Bold, Bold}},
        ItemSize -> {5, Automatic}, Spacings -> {0, 0}}] //
    TraditionalForm
```

[image: buttons-table]

Answer (score 3):

With [`Tooltips`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tooltips.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

func = {Sin, Cos, Tan};

quad = Range[Pi/4, 2 Pi, Pi/2];

signs =
  Outer[
   Tooltip[
     Sign[#1[#2]] /. {1 -> "+", -1 -> "-"},
     Show[
      Plot[#1[theta], {theta, 0, 2 Pi},
       PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[0.5]],
      Plot[#1[theta], {theta, #2 - Pi/4, #2 + Pi/4},
       PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}]]] &,
   func, quad];

table = Map[Button, Flatten /@ Transpose[
     {Decapitalize[ToString[#]] <> " θ" & /@ func, 
      signs}], {2}];

header =
  {{Button["", Background -> LightBlue,
      Appearance -> "DialogBox"],
     Button["Quadrant", Background -> LightBlue,
      Appearance -> "DialogBox"], SpanFromLeft},
    Button[#, Background -> LightBlue,
       Appearance -> "DialogBox"] & /@
     ({"Ratio", 
        RomanNumeral /@ Range[4]} // Flatten)} /.
   str_String :> Style[str, Bold];

Flatten[{header, table}, 1] //
 Grid[#,
   Spacings -> {0.15, 0.15},
   Background -> Darker[LightBlue, 0.075]] &
```

[image]

Comment: Super helpful,  will for sure use this in the next course where they actually study graphing of trig functions.